# Is there a method to compute pca of a Surface_mesh object in CGAL?

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm new to the CGAL library. and I want to compute PCA of a Surface_mesh object.

```
CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Point_3> mesh;
std::ifstream cactus("cat.off");
cactus >> mesh;
```

As I mentioned in the CGAL documents for computing PCA, just computing PCA for a set of points or triangles is discussed [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Principal_component_analysis/index.html).

I have tried bellow code  to fit a line but an error raised:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/linear_least_squares_fitting_3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

typedef double                      FT;
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<FT>  K;
typedef K::Line_3                   Line;
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Point_3> SM;

int main(void)
{
    Line line;
    SM mesh;
    std::ifstream cat("cat.off");
    cat >> mesh;
    linear_least_squares_fitting_3(mesh.faces_begin(),mesh.faces_end(),line, CGAL::Dimension_tag<0>());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example that demonstrates the problem? that is, it would be useful to have a short snippet of code that I can compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

The value type of the iterator passed to [linear_least_squares_fitting_3](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Principal_component_analysis/group__PkgPrincipalComponentAnalysisDLLSF3.html#gadcf556c115c6bac30a54bf7fdd0d32e3) can only be a geometric Kernel type. However, you can either construct a vector of `Triangle_3` and pass this range to the function, or directly use [boost's transform iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html) in conjunction with a simple struct that constructs a `Triangle_3` from a `Surface_mesh`'s face.